# Angular Material mat-table apply multiple checkbox filter on single column then search further

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to filter a single column in mat-table with multiple values then perform a further search on the resulted rows, I've searched everywhere but couldn't find an example similar to that.

I want to achieve something like this
[Table image with filters & search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPg9E.png)

So here i can apply ball color on 'Balls' column then search further on the result

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction with an small example if possible, really struggling with this one

Answer (score 0):

Go to this stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datatable-multi-column-filter?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts
and replace code of this file table-filtering-example.ts with this code and search in position and name columns

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { COMMA, TAB, SPACE, ENTER } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: string;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export interface SearchItem {
  name: string;
}


const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: '999', name: 'test', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: '112', name: '999', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: '113', name: '998', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },

];

/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  positionFilter = new FormControl();
  nameFilter = new FormControl();
  private filterValues = { position: '', name: '' }

  filteredValues = {
    position: '', name: '', weight: '',
    symbol: '', topFilter: false
  };

  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [COMMA, TAB, ENTER];
  searchItems: SearchItem[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.positionFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((positionFilterValue) => {
      console.log(positionFilterValue);

      this.filterValues['position'] = positionFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
      //this.filteredValues['topFilter'] = false;
    });


    this.nameFilter.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.filterValues['name'] = value
        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues)
      });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
  }

    add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    console.log('event', event);

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.searchItems.push({name: value.trim()});
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  remove(item: SearchItem): void {
    const index = this.searchItems.indexOf(item);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.searchItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }


  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    let filter = {
      name: filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(),
      position: filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(),
      topFilter: true
    }
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(filter)
  }

  createFilter() {
    let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
      let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter)
      let idSearch = () => {
        let found = false;
        if (data.position.indexOf(searchTerms.position) != -1) { found = true }
        return found
      }
      let nameSearch = () => {
        let found = false;
        searchTerms.name.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
          if (data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1) { found = true }
        });
        return found
      }
      return idSearch() && nameSearch()
    }
    return filterFunction
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex because there're many element to take account. A big step you can see in [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887051/angular-5-material-table-replace-filterpredicate-with-function-that-has-differen)

Yes, the "key" is change the function `filterPredicate`, as this function should to have two mandatory parameters, the "element" and a "string" that make filter, we can imagine that the filter string is a JSON.stringify of an object in the way (I only make it with size)

```
{
  filter:'u',
  size:['small']
}
```

So we can indicate in ngOnInit that our function filter is

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (
  data: PeriodicElement,
  filter: string
) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(filter);
  let find: boolean = !obj.filter && !obj.size;
  if (obj.filter) {
    const value =
      '~' +
      data.position +
      '~' +
      data.name +
      '~' +
      data.weight +
      '~' +
      data.symbol +
      '~';
    find = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(obj.filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  } else find = true;

  if (obj.size) find = find && obj.size.indexOf(data.size) >= 0;
  return find;
};
```

Well, as always we has a series of "inputs" we need use template driven forms or reactiveForms. I love Reactive Forms, so I define a form like

```
form = new FormGroup({
    filter: new FormControl(),
    size: new FormControl()
  });
```

See that, althought in size we want to store an array, I use a FormControl. The use of reactive Forms, makes that we can -also in ngInit- subscribe to valueChanges. In subscribe simply indicate that the property filter of the dataSource is the JSON.stringify(res)

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
  this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(res);
});
```

And it's all about your question: "change the filter function"

Well, there're another aspect that is how manage the form and the inputs. I goin to use two auxiliars functions:

```
  isChecked(field: string, value: string) {
    const control = this.form.get(field);
    return control && control.value && control.value.indexOf(value) >= 0;
  }

  change(list:any[],field: string, value: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const control = this.form.get(field);
    const oldValue = control ? control.value || [] : [];
    if (control) {
      if (!isChecked) {
        const newValue = oldValue.filter((x: string) => x != value);
        control.setValue(newValue.length > 0 ? newValue : null);
      } else {
        const newValue = list.filter(
          x => oldValue.indexOf(x) >= 0 || x == value
        );
        control.setValue(newValue);
      }
    }
  }
```

That allow me manage a serie of check-boxes. So, if we has an array like

```
sizes = ['big', 'small'];
```

I can use in the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let size of sizes" class="example-margin"
  [checked]="isChecked('size',size)" (change)="change(sizes,'size',size,$event.checked)"
  >
    {{size}}
    </mat-checkbox>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="filter" placeholder="Ex. ium" #input>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

the [final stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gksb9g?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts)

Comment: Omg thank you so much I was able to achieve my task, but I still have some requests,  A. What does '~' do in filterPredicate.   B.   I would like some advice on how/what should I do to learn this stuff on my own. Thanks again

Comment: @gtXs, you create a string. I choose create a string with the values of the "row" separate by a character ~. So, imagine you type `gen`.  I look the "word" `gen` into, e.g. `~1~Hydrogen~1.0079~H~`, and return true (in a string like `2~Helium~4.0026~He~` return false). I would search in a string like `1Hydrogen1.0079H`, but this makes that if I type `gen1` return true -and there' not "element" with name with gen1.

Comment: @gtXs, There are some interesting that is how read the "docs". If you lpok in material docs about a component you has a tab with "API". Properties that are "Inputs" you can use in html like `[NameProperty]="variable"` or, in .ts `nameObject.Property=value`, the properties that are "Outputs" are "events", so you can use in .html `(nameOfOutput)="myfunction($event)"`. In .ts you write `myfunction(variable:any){...}` see that the "output are in the way `EventEmitter<OneType>`,so the variable you received is of type "OneType". The "methods" are function that you can call in .ts `myObject.method()`

Comment: At last, the better way to learn is ask about you don't understand and try to understand a code before "copy and paste". In Angular is good take the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to share your knowledge with me, I'll definitely keep in mind to follow all the points mentioned above